# python, split, regex and combine re

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pyspark

I have a data in key value format.

```
key=1234 key1="value in text"
```

I want to create single regex to split the value of individual key.

for Example:

- key={regex} must return 1234
- key1={regex} must return "value in text"

```
regex="key=\"(.*?)\"|key=([^ ]*)"
```

I have tried this regex but it is not working. Could you please help me?

I want to split the string in such a way to get the result in tabular format with the help regex and spark.

key   | key1        |
Value |Value in text|

Comment: could you give a reproducible data in python. ie something we can just copy and paste into python. `string = 'key=1234 key1="value in text"'` is that how your data looks like?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use regex? This is trivial to parse into a ``dict`` using string methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyPi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and a code like

```py
import regex
text = 'key=1234 key1="value in text"'
# key = 'key1' # => value in text
key = 'key' # => 1234
pattern = fr'\b{regex.escape(key)}=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S*))'
match = regex.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # => 1234
```

See the [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY3LDoIwEEX3/YpJWbQlhgRxZVL9CJeiSSXDIwo0pRiI@O21IIlxVpN7zszVoy3bJnGuqnVrLBgscCAWBwsS2B1HGW@THfgllvSpHj1C1cDMKSPBnK9ezCAAeYA/h/z4iudvRCtr0TSe5Ialt9dSGmGXKY3cu@It@XGi/Hyll1DQiaenUAhGamWz0l99/Q6VyUq@PtsshYJUOSzanoAfbarG8iWICtP2msdCOPcB). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `{regex.escape(key)}` - the key passed to the regex
- `=` - an equal sign
- `(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S*))` - a *[branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)* matching

  - `"([^"]*)"` - a `"` char, then zero or more chars other than `"` captured into Group 1 and then a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S*)` - Group 1 (again, as it is a branch reset group): zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Here is my ["Branch reset groups - capture different patterns into same groups"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rAQlhl7eyA) YT video showcasing the use of branch reset groups.

Comment: what if I want to split the key=value pair and fetch value from it

Comment: @AnuRadha No idea what you mean. If you want to get the `key=value`, just return `match.group()`, the whole match.

Comment: I want to split the string and want to convert  the key value pair in tabular format.

Key    | Key1             |
value | Value in text |

Comment: @AnuRadha you have just "converted" your question into a new one. `pyspark` is quite a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

If the contexts of the string are valid, ie everything after the key is just encapsulated within the quotation marks, then I would prefer to parse the string to a dictionary and get the values you want:

```
import re

string = 'key=1234 key1="value in text"'
replace =  lambda x: (', ' if x.group(1) else '') + f'"{x.group(2)}":'

my_dict = eval(re.sub(r'(\s)?(\w+)=',replace, f"{{{string}}}"))

my_dict['key']
# out[23] 1234

my_dict['key1']
# out[24] 'value in text'
```